# Applying SMOTE to a feature-set with both text and numerical

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

I am trying to train a RF Classifier on a dataset that has both a textual description feature and other categorical features. There is heavy class imbalance, so a need for SMOTE Upsampling prior to the fitting of the model. As SMOTE cannot be applied to text, I would need to vectorize this one feature before upsampling, which works fine by itself, but I am not sure how to incorporate the other features as well.

I tried taking the ColumnTransformer and Pipeline approach:

```
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
[('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer, 'description')],
remainder='passthrough')

pipeline = ImbPipeline([
('column_transformer', column_transformer),
('smote', smote),
('model', model)
])
```

That fails, as smote cannot be applied before the transformation; and the other way around with the CT before does not fail but seems like it doesn't apply SMOTE at all, getting the same results as without it. Any help ?

Comment: Your code and description of the failures seem swapped: as written the transformer _does_ come before smote.

Comment: "with the CT before does not fail but seems like it doesn't apply SMOTE at all, getting the same results as without it." What exactly do you mean here? Model score?  You can resample using just the first two steps to verify that it's working, or the forest can be inspected to see how many samples were seen by each tree.

Comment: @BenReiniger Yea they are swapped mb. I'm trying the CT before smote, but i'm not sure how to check the issue of the pipeline to see if it worked